# Facebook Get User ID From Application Tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

Facebook apps are allowed to have a tab that a user can add to his profile's tabs if he wants.

How can I get the uid or otherwise identify the currently logged in user in order to customize the layout for him please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/):

> Facebook does not pass back who the viewing user is when she first visits your tab. Facebook does send the profile owner's ID in the fb_sig_profile_user parameter, so you know whose profile to display content for.

Visitor id is passed as request parameter after a user interacts with your tab. I can't find exact parameter name as they removed a wiki page that used to contain a list of all passed parameters, but if you dump all your request vars you should be able to see it (but not during the first visit).

Comment: I see. What I want is to have the TAB customized for the user who "owns" the tab, like with Trip Advisor's Cities Visited: http://www.facebook.com/CitiesIveVisited?v=info#!/profile.php?id=100000435638686&v=app_2219089314&ref=ts

Also, I have to say, Facebook developer community is very poor in my oppinion. Wiki posts get deleted or moved all the time too. :(

Comment: Just to make sure: if the link isn't visible, it shows a map with cities visited by the user who has that tab in his profile.

How do they do that? If I had the FB ID of the user who has that tab it would be simple...

Comment: @Francisc if you need profile owner id then just read `fb_sig_profile_user` request parameter on your server side. You can get owner id, just not the visitor.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I wanted.

Thanks a lot, Serg!

Answer (score 2):

some sources to do it + you must have turned on all items on migration in app settings

http://nathrondevblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-get-user-id-in-profile-tab.html

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one,
If the user is logged in. You can directly get the user_id, session_key etc from the querystring.

```
       long fbuid = long.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get("fb_sig_user"));
```